# Недавно я случайно удалил весь файл «путь» (переменная среды), возможно, в нем не хватает какой-то переменной. вот мой флаттер-доктор:

Tags: cmd, firebase, flutter, dart, path

**Проблема:** Недавно я случайно удалил весь файл «путь» (переменная среды), возможно, в нем не хватает какой-то переменной.

Вот мой **флаттер-доктор**:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.8.0-14.0.pre.8, in Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19044.2604],     localization ru-RU)
[√] Windows version (installed version of Windows - version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - development for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - development for the Internet
[!] Visual Studio - development for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
X Visual Studio lacks the necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop Development using C++" workload and enable these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Build Tools
- If multiple versions of the build tool are available, install the latest one
C++ CMake Tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[√] Connected device (available 3)
[√] Network resources
```

Вроде нормально, но когда я пишу в консоль `dart ...`
или `flutterfire ...` или просто `dart` - сразу закрывается без ошибок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя переменная пользовательской среды PATH
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался переустановить `flutter sdk`, но это не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема была локализована с помощью powershell: при запуске команды dart ... через cmd окно просто исчезало, но стоило запустить её (например dart --version) черех powershell как тотчас отобразилась истинная причина ошибки

> Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

ответ был найден сразу: git должен быть установлен в переменные окружения